# chrome.serial API docs for Chrome 31?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Are the old docs for the chrome.serial API available anywhere? It seems that they have updated them for the [Dev Channel version](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html) (33), but I'm trying to develop an App that people can use right now without having to install Canary.

Also, will the new API completely kill all the existing apps using the older API when the browsers do update to 33?

Comment: Try WayBackMachine at `http://archive.org/web/` with same link.

Comment: Wow I hadn't thought of that, it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just look at the API IDL files directly at the Chromium code repo.  As of this writing, the stable channel is on 31.0.1650.63.  The branch number is therefore 1650, so the API is at http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/branches/1650/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/serial.idl